# How to update the cached file when updating our application?

Tags: angular

I am developing web app in angular and I face one issue many times that when I update the build on server and open the app on server URL then all the time I need to clear my browser cache. If I do not do this then the older pages are load and this effect my angular app performance.

I tried 2 methods

1)

```
meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" 


meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" 


meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" 


meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" 


meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"
```

2) At the build time, `ng build --prod --outputHashing=all`

Comment: are you fetching the values from the SQL or all the pages are facing the same issue. Is max-age=0 taking affect. Can you see the cache being cleared once the max-age=0 is set?

Comment: my html content are also not updated when i open it in same browser where previous build updated web page . But if i open it in browser incognito mode then it will show me the updated page.